# VBA Find & Replace

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm using Excel VBA to generate word documents from a spreadsheet. I want to find and replace all double paragraphs with single paragraphs as part of the last step.

Base code:

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objSelection

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.TypeText "Test"
objSelection.TypeText (vbCr)
objSelection.TypeText (vbCr)
objWord.Visible = True
```

Finding and replacing basic text works:

```
With objWord.ActiveDocument
    Set myRange = .Content
    With myRange.Find
        .Execute FindText:="test", ReplaceWith:="apple", Replace:=2
    End With
End With
```

Finding and replacing paragraphs does NOT work:

```
With objWord.ActiveDocument
    Set myRange = .Content
    With myRange.Find
        .Execute FindText:="^^p", ReplaceWith:="^p", Replace:=2
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

`.Execute FindText:="^^p", ReplaceWith:="^p", Replace:=2`

to

`.Execute FindText:="^p^p", ReplaceWith:="^p", Replace:=2`

Comment: Wow I can't believe I overlooked that... thank you so much. I feel like a fool :p

Comment: @Dar It happens! :)