# Excel vba remove empty lines in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Since I do find 'n replace from Excel VBA in Word I have to remove blank/empty lines in Word.

This is my current code:

```
Sub xyz()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Word.Range

Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Cur_dir_var & "\!Automatisering gegevens template.docx")
For Each wdRng In wdDoc.StoryRanges



'~~> Find 'n replace
With wdRng.Find
                .Text = "<Project naam>"
                .Replacement.Text = Project_naam_var
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

                .Text = "<Klant>"
                .Replacement.Text = Klant_var
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

Next wdRng

'~~> Save as
wdDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:=Cur_dir_var & "\" & Worksheets("Algemeen").Range("B3").Value & " Automatisering gegevens.docx"

'~~> Quit
    wdApp.Quit

'~~> Clean up
Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would like to remove all the empty lines in my Word document.. How can I do this the best possible way and implement it into my current code?

Thank you in advance!!

EXAMPLE:

```
<netwerk1_naam_var>
<netwerk1_merk_var>
<netwerk1_type_var>
<netwerk1_ip_var>
<netwerk1_subnet_var>
<netwerk1_Username_var>
<netwerk1_Password_var>
<netwerk1_MAC_var>
<ENTER>
<netwerk2_naam_var>
<netwerk2_merk_var>
<netwerk2_type_var>
<netwerk2_ip_var>
<netwerk2_subnet_var>
<netwerk2_Username_var>
<netwerk2_Password_var>
<netwerk2_MAC_var>
<ENTER>
```

Comment: You first need to define exactly what you mean by "empty lines".  Right off-hand, an "empty line" could be three things: 1) paragraph containing only the paragraph character (`Chr(13)`); 2) a line within a paragraph created by pressing Shift+Enter (`Chr(10)`); 3) `SpaceBefore` and/or `SpaceAfter` paragraph formatting. Each of these can be found using Word's built-in `Find` functionality. The first two can be found using a special character ( `^p` resp. `^l`) and replaced by "nothing" (`""`); the third is a bit trickier... A picture with text-wrap formatting could also generate empty space.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you for this quick reply. I want to remove every empty line which means that every enter which is creating an empty line in a Word document should be removed.

EXAMPLE -> see original post

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50025665/3077495

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Find & Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025665/vba-find-replace)

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you a lot! This helps me a bit more. Still not the result I'm looking for. What means this "Replace:=2"?

Comment: How is it not the result you want? `2` is `wdReplaceAll` which means it does the entire document in one action.