# Find and replace filename in formula and recalculate formula

Tags: excel, vba

This may be a simple question to you but I  need this code because otherwise I have to do much repetitive work.

I'm looking for VBA code that does the following:

- Finds and replaces a specified string (link to source - let's say "file1" with "file2") and then get new values from changed excel file.

For example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3;file1!A1;7;FALSE)
```

and replaces it with

```
=VLOOKUP(A3;file2!A1;7;FALSE)
```

I tried this but it asks me like 100x to confirm/search the file on every change.

```
name = InputBox("your file name")

Cells.Replace What:="file1", Replacement:=name, LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

An example to make it more clear:

I download an Excel file from another program and the numbers change every week. I also have my own excel where is vlookup function to find specific numbers from  downloaded excel.

Now I am trying to get the Excel to copy new numbers from another file just by changing the link to another Excel. Let's say I have three excel files: MyTemplate, Week1_figures and Week2_figures.  I would like to find all Week1_figures in MyTemplate and replace all of them with Week2_figures AND then the numbers would change.

```
=VLOOKUP(A3;Week1_figures!A1;7;FALSE)
```

-->

```
=VLOOKUP(A3;Week2_figures!A1;7;FALSE)
```

I tried the code above but it always makes me search that specific file. (Week2_figures in this case)

Can you guys help me? 
Is there other way to do this?

If anything here is unclear, Ill try to help clear it up. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So... the question is how not to repeat the same input over and over? Or...? **Well... what even is the question?**

Comment: The syntax change in your example changes the worksheet within a single workbook. It doesn't change workbooks, i.e. *files*.

Comment: Do you have hundreds of values to search for? If not, a regular find and replace should work (search term `file1!` replace with `file2!`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Find & Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025665/vba-find-replace)

Answer (score 5):

> I tried this but it asks me like 100x to confirm/search the file on every change.

You can temporarily disable confirmations with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.

```
name = InputBox("your file name")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Cells.Replace What:="file1", Replacement:=name, LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: The formula you supplied only looks up a single cell in a single cell and references a return column that is out of range so it is useless as an example. If you get #N/A then it isn't finding a match.

Comment: If I have the files in the same folder, how can I get it to automatically read that file? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: Build a formula that works with File1. Underneath that, build another formula that works with File2. Look closely at the differences between the two.