# Delete "blank" lines defined by two consecutive paragraph marks

Tags: vba, ms-word

I could not get the code at [VBA Find & Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025665/vba-find-replace)
to work for me, as it gives an "Automation Error - Call was refused by Callee" error.

I already have an open word file that I am trying to remove instances of 2 paragraph marks in a row, and replace them with one.
I declare objWord as Object `Dim objWord As Object` and then use the code from the link as:

```
   
       Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'get the Word open session
           
         With objWord.ActiveDocument
            Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
            With myRange.Find
            .Execute FindText:="^p^p", ReplaceWith:="^p", Replace:=2
       End With
End With
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How many instances of MS Word (**WINWORD.EXE**) are running, check it from the Task Manager( Ctrl + Shift + Esc in Windows).
2. Be sure `GetObject(, "Word.Application")` returns the WINWORD.EXE IS you want to OP.
3. Are you sure the `ActiveDocument` in that `objWord` is the one which you want to OP? If you can, try to avoid using the ActiveDocument object, and assign a Document to a Document object variable instead.
4. use the `ClearFormatting` method of Find object before [`Execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute).
5. You forget to set the `Wrap` argument. It would be better to use `Forward` along with it.
6. If you insist to use the `GetObject` method you can directly assign the document file to it to get the right Document object you want to OP. like this:

```vb
    Dim d As Object 'Word.Document
    Set d = GetObject("D:\your file fullname string.docx")
```

Comment: Thank you it now works. You were right that I was getting the wrong instance of word. Hence your suggestion resolved my issue